# Looking for Continuous Integration solutions for a specific scenario

Tags: linux, continuous-integration

I'm working on a cross-platform library that targets Linux/Mac/Windows versions. I want to get my project into a CI. I can't decide which integration system is best for our scenario. There are many success stories with each system, and they are much more complex to test and compare. So I'm here to provide my requirements and ask for your suggestions.

- The CI should be OpenSource and free (as in freedom)
- Technology stack should not matter. Currently we are using C++/Autoconf/Automake and C++/Qt, but we should be able to test PHP or Java projects.
- Build server should be installed on a local server running multiple virtual machines (Windows XP x86 - Windows 7 x86 - Windows 7 x86_64 - Ubuntu Server x86 - Ubuntu Server x86_64 each one loads a snapshot and compiles library, git clone - configure - compile - test... )
- GIT integration. CI should support basic features. For example automatic builds after commits. More advanced integration is desired. For example by adding pre-defined tokens to commit messages I would like to say "hey don't build this comment, It's a documentation typo..."

There requirements are not necessary but desired:

- Nice web interface or GUI backend
- Bugtracker integration
- Email notifications
- Scheduled builds

CI systems I'm considering to test are:

- Buildbot
- Jenekins
- Hudson
- CrouseControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI Server Comparison/Feature Matrix tables:

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software

and http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix